# Django IntegrityError 'Column tag_id cannot be null'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I'll describe the models first and explain the issue i'm having after.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(_(u'id'), max_length=128, primary_key=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I execute this code I get the error in the subject:

```
post_obj = Post.objects.get(id='someid')
tag_obj = Tag.objects.get(id='')
post_obj.tags.add(tag_obj)
```

Notice how the tag id is an empty string.

I've looked into what sql is being executed and it looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `post_tags` (`post_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES ('someid', NULL)
```

The empty string tag_id is being converted into a NULL value.

Mysql show columns output from post_tag (manytomany table):

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id             | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id              | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So django is converting my empty string to NULL when adding the tag. How can I stop django from doing this?